# Strings with special characters not rendering correctly in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, string, text

I'm quite new to JavaScript and HTML. I'm trying to write a program that takes in a number and spits out garbled text (containing all sorts of special characters and symbols; here's a sample: `@;f%UA@;f%UDaVI*&e"q+/[)`).

My JavaScript code takes in an input number and generates a string of garbled characters, which is then displayed on a paragraph on the page (using `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML`) and simultaneously copied to clipboard. The program seems to work as intended for the most part, but whenever the garbled output string contains a left angular bracket (`<`), the text in the paragraph is not displayed completely.

Here's a sample output:

- Garbled string: `K@8K@<v`I,= ]1h<r50\ `
- Output in the page body: `K@8K@`

Even the above code formatting is broken at the left angular bracket `<`, which leads me to suspect that this may be caused by an escape sequence or something similar. I'd be very glad if someone can suggest a way to fix this issue with the text rendering.

Comment: This has nothing to do with “escape sequences”, but with the meaning `<` and `>` simply _have_ in HTML. You don’t _want_ what you created interpreted as HTML, you want it treated as text - so don’t use `.innerHTML`, use `.innerText` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try this out in my code and get back.

Comment: Your suggestion works as intended. Thanks for the help. If you post this comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with “escape sequences”, but with the meaning `<` and `>` simply *have* in HTML.

The browser thinks you are stating an HTML *tag* with `<…` – and tags do not *show* on screen in HTML, they are part of the *structure*.

You don’t *want* what you created interpreted as HTML, you want it treated as text - so don’t use `.innerHTML`, use `.innerText` instead.

Answer (score 3):

For me, what fixed the issue was adding `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in the `<head>` section.